# Single word meaning either "liked" or "disliked"

Tags: word-choice

I have a forum where you can Like a reply. After you press that button it changes from Like to Liked. Now I want to add a Dislike button so I would like to replace the "Liked" text for something that would also include "Disliked". I think the word should be close to something like "Done", "Voted", or "Pressed" but also related with the original text.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: To avoid the issue, you could just say "Thanks" or "Thanks for voting".

Comment: I think you should use *Liked* for liking and *Disliked* for disliking.  Is that not an option?

Comment: Take a leaf out of ELU's book, and just use Up/Down arrows with no static text at all. If you can make a display layout where the meaning is clear without using any words at all, that's normally the best option.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to UX SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not actually an answer to your question, but as a forum user I would prefer to see whether I liked or disliked something instead of just seeing the fact that I am "done" with it.  Is there anything wrong with keeping Liked or Disliked?

Here are some alternatives if you want to really have a generic word:

- Responded
- Designated
- Marked
- Acknowledged

Comment: I agree from a web-development perspective:  what's wrong with having it read "Liked" or "Disliked" depending on which action was taken?

Comment: @Brendon OK I will spend some time at Stackoverflow then.

Answer (score 2):

I do usability work for a living and I recommend reporting whether they *liked* it or *disliked* it as opposed to a general note such as *thanks for voting*...  In fact, most sites will show a thumbs-up or down highlighting the documented action (*e.g. [Digg](http://www.digg.com)*).  The terms made popular by [*Redditt*](http://www.reddit.com/) I believe are *upvoted* and *downvoted*.  [*Netflix*](http://netflix.com) is also a very popular reference with a star-rating highlighting the number of stars given to a movie.  So stating you "up-voted this", "gave a 4-star rating", or highlighting the documented action may be more appropriate and user-friendly than a "thank you" message.

You may also want to consider posting something like this on the User Experience Exchange, 
https://ux.stackexchange.com/